# How to use TrustWallet DApp browser with WalletConnect?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, trust, walletconnect, trustwallet

I need to integrate my Dapp with Trust Wallet's internal DApp browser. I followed [this instruction](https://developer.trustwallet.com/wallet-connect/dapp) on the trust wallet website. However, when I run my DApp inside the trust wallet DApp browser, it shows a mobile tab with a connect button and when I press that button, the current web page simply redirects to google to search for WalletConnect standard URI, i.e. `wc:00e46b69-d0cc-4b3e-b6a2-cee442f97188...` (it seems that DApp browser does not understand that format).
Additionally, when I access my Dapp through a mobile browser such as Firefox on android, it opens the trust wallet and connects to it successfully, but no further transactions are getting shown on the wallet to confirm. Only on the desktop browsers everything works smoothly (when I connect through QR code).
Is there any special consideration or requirement to integrate a Dapp with trust wallet internal browser?

Comment: As a consider I highly discourage to use any wallet internal browsers, as they tend to be very buggy and hard to develop against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was brought about by the Trust wallet itself and after upgrading to the latest version (4.9 on android), the issue is now solved and everything works as expected.